# Java command not working in docker container

Tags: java, docker

I am trying to run java with docker image in gitlab.

Here is my docker file.

```
  FROM java:latest
  FROM perl
  COPY . /
  ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/perl", "/myapp_entrypoint.pl"]
```

I was able to build docker image successfully and run perl commands but java commands are not working.

My application is a linux application and I am running `'java -version'`. I am not getting any output completely blank output for version command.

What would be the issue? Do I need to add anything related linux as I am running `'java -version'` as linux command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify what OS you're running in your container, but the main issue is that you're blowing away your Java layer with another `FROM` directive.

From [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from), emphasis mine:

> Each `FROM` instruction **clears any state** created by previous instructions.

So I'd espouse a solution in which I install Perl (if I *really* needed to) after having my base Java image.

**However**, if you use the base [OpenJDK images](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/), Perl comes preinstalled, so that will simplify your Dockerfile significantly.

```
FROM openjdk:latest
COPY . /
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/perl", "/myapp_entrypoint.pl"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working now. One doubt , If FROM removing previous state then what if I have more than 1 dependancies and I want to utilize all of them? Like in my problem I need both perl and java .So, what if openjdk image is not having in-built perl?

Comment: @Rekha:  Install it like you would on any modern OS.  Specify the command line argument (yum, apt, etc) and perform an installation of what you need in your Dockerfile.

Comment: An example would be more helpful to understand this. Could you provide an example ?